# Battery stops charging at 84% and gets very hot

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, temperature, hp-pavilion

My laptop battery always charges to about `84%` to `87%`. Once it reaches a charge level in that range, it stops charging, but Windows says it is "plugged in and charging". Because it has not reached 100%, it keeps trying to charge the battery, but instead of charging it gets very hot. It causes CPU temperatures of about `51°C` (normal temperatures range from `35°C` when idle, to `43°C` when running an IDE and a compiler).

The machine is an HP Pavilion dv7-6157cl running Windows 7. I have set the fan in the BIOS to run continuously, and it is always on a table or some surface which allows plenty of airflow to the vents on the bottom.

I have reinstalled the battery drivers and updated all of the other drivers. Nothing seems to help. I have also tried calibrating the battery. I also tried changing several power settings. The problem persists.

However, it works correctly as long as the charge does not exceed `84%`.

What might be causing the problem? Is there a way I can get Windows to stop charging the battery at about `80%`? Should I get a new battery?

Comment: Is it a Li-Ion battery?

Comment: Battery heating can be a sign that there's a bad cell in the stack. The other cells charge up to full capacity and the bad cell then just turns into a resistor, creating a lot of heat as it dissipates the wasted current, and in the case of Li-Poly, eventually smoke.

Comment: @ChristopherChipps It is a 9-cell Lithium-ion battery.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Interesting. If one cell in the stack is bad, the maximum possible percentage would be `88%`. I am thinking that is probably what is wrong. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Battery heating can be a sign that there's a bad cell in the stack.

The other cells charge up to full capacity and the bad cell then just turns into a resistor, creating a lot of heat as it dissipates the wasted current, and in the case of Li-Poly, eventually smoke.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your battery. Fiasco Labs is right. Your battery is broken and needs replacing.